# Load Images After Bootstrap Modal Is Opened

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

After trying many solutions from Stackoverflow, I'm want to see if someone can help.  I'm using this template - https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/agency/. At this time, the images are loading when the pages loads.  I want the images to load when the modal is opened.

**What's working:**

```
$('img[src="img/port/wait-images.jpg"]').each(function(index, el) {
    $(el).attr('src', $(el).data('real-src'));
});
var globalLazyLoad = new LazyLoad();

<img class="img-fluid" src="img/port/wait-images.jpg" data-real-src="img/port/the-real-image.jpg" alt="">
```

This code displays the wait image but only when the page loads.

**The Problem:**

I want certain images to load when the modal is opened.

Answer (score 0):

You should make that lazyload method fire on the open modal call.

```
function loadImagesToModal(){
  $('img[src="img/port/wait-images.jpg"]').each(function(index, el) {
    $(el).attr('src', $(el).data('real-src'));
  });
}
$({the modal's class}).on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    loadImagesToModal();
})
```

That way you can have them swap over only on that event

Comment: I  added the .portfolio-modal as the modal's class but only shows the wait-image.  What am I doing wrong?                                                                                                                         function loadImagesToModal(){
  $('img[src="img/port/wait-images.jpg"]').each(function(index, el) {
    $(el).attr('src', $(el).data('real-src'));
  });
}
$({.portfolio-modal}).on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    loadImagesToModal();
})

Comment: Should the image tag stay as - <img class="img-fluid" src="img/port/wait-images.jpg" data-real-src="img/port/the-real-image.jpg" alt=""> ?